# Asterisk exit queue and reenter queue without losing position

Tags: asterisk

I want to give my customers an option to press 1 if they wish to listen to no music on hold. Sometimes is annoying to keep listening to the same song lol. Anywyas this is what I have:

**queues.conf:**

```
[general]
    persistentmembers=yes

[Support]
    context=Common-Queue    
    member=>SIP/Jhon
    member=>SIP/Tom
```

**extensions.conf:**

```
...
same => n,Playback(Press1ToListenToNoMusicOnHold) ; plays audio file that says that caller may press 1 if he wishes to listen to no music on hold
same => n,Queue(SupportQueue,Tt)  ; option T is so that caller can exit queue by pressing digits jumping to an extension
... etc

; context Common-Queue
[Common-Queue]
exten => 1,1,NoOp(enable user to not listen to music)
same => n,Set(CHANNEL(musicclass)=no-music) ; 
same => n,Queue(Support) ; enter support queue again
same => n,Hangup()
```

With this scenario the music on hold is removed if the user presses 1 and the user goes back to the Support queue (this is exactly what I need). **The problem with this solution is that if the user presses 1 then it loses its position in the queue**. How can I solve this problem without the customer losing its position in the queue? I want to give my customers the option to wait with no music on hold without losing its place in the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a way to do it. If you look at the queue command it looks like this:

> Queue(queuename[,options[,URL[,announceoverride[,timeout[,AGI[,macro[,gosub[,rule[,position]]]]]]]]])

When you exit the queue the variable `QUEUEPOSITION` is populated with the position that you had on the queue. **So the solution is to reenter the support queue as:**

```
 same => n,Queue(Support,,,,,,,,,${QUEUEPOSITION})
```